# Как инкапсулировать navigation cotroller в tab bar controller? (Программно)

Tags: swift, uikit

Имеется стартовый *tab bar*

```
import UIKit

class StartTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        generateTabBar()
    }
    
    private func generateTabBar() {
        viewControllers = [
            generateVC(viewController: FirstViewController(), title: "first tab"),
            generateVC(viewController: SecondViewController(), title: "second tab"),
            generateVC(viewController: ThirdViewController(), title: "third tab")
        ]
    }
    
    private func generateVC(viewController: UIViewController, title: String) -> UIViewController {
        viewController.tabBarItem.title = title
        return viewController
    }
    
}
```

*FirstViewController* выглядит следующим образом (с ним проблем нет, все работает как нужно):

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    let button = UIButton()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupViews()
        setupConstraints()
    }
    
    func setupViews() {
        button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 30)
        button.addAction(
            UIAction(
                handler: { [weak self] _ in
                    let alert = self?.createAlert() ?? UIAlertController()
                    self?.present(
                        alert,
                        animated: true,
                        completion: nil
                    )
                }),
            for: .touchUpInside
        )
        view.addSubview(button)
    }
    
    private func setupConstraints() {
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        button.centerYAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    private func createAlert() -> UIAlertController {
        let alert = UIAlertController(
            title: "This is the last screen",
            message: "Please, go back",
            preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(
            title: "Okey",
            style: .default,
            handler: nil
            ))
        
        return alert
    }
    
}
```

А вот c *SecondViewController* имеется проблема. При нажатии на кнопку, не создается стек из вью

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: FirstViewController {
    
    override func setupViews() {
        button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 30)
        button.addAction(
            UIAction(
                handler: { [weak self] _ in
                    self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondViewController(), animated: true)
                }),
            for: .touchUpInside
        )
        view.addSubview(button)
    }
    
}
```

Как это все исправить, не меняя *SceneDelegate* ???

```
guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window?.rootViewController = StartTabBarController()
```

По совету GPT попробовал сделать так, но не вышло(

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: FirstViewController {
    
    override func setupViews() {
        super.setupViews()
        
        button.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents)
        
        button.addAction(
            UIAction(
                handler: { [weak self] _ in
                    let thirdVC = ThirdViewController()
                    self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(thirdVC, animated: true)
                }),
            for: .touchUpInside
        )
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите вот здесь https://habr.com/ru/articles/652543/

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно было дополнить метод *generateVC* в *StartTabBarController*

```
private func generateVC(viewController: UIViewController, title: String) -> UIViewController {
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
        navigationController.tabBarItem.title = title
        return navigationController
    }
```